# How to search for questions without a specific tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

How do I search on a Stack Exchange for questions *without* a specific tag, for example questions without the [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

**Edit:** Why is this question marked as dubplicate? In this question I asked to search for questions **without** a specific tag. The question mentioned is *"How do I search for questions **with** specific tags?"* ?

Comment: It's duplicate because the answer is given there as well. It is a general faq, and the tag negation is also mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negation. In other words:

[is:q -[code-golf]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+-%5Bcode-golf%5D)

(You must also give either a search term or operator. In your case you want only questions, so `is:q` fits.)

From [search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

> To *exclude* results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with `-` in your query: `waffles -unicorns` finds posts that mention tasty batter-based breakfasts without including mythical creatures, while `[laurel] -[hardy]` includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple.